# Signals in Linux

Tags: programming-languages, linux, signals

I am studying signals from oreilly book. I came across this.

```
#include <signal.h>
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);----> func ptr returns void. uses typedef 
sighandler_t signal (int signo, sighandler_t handler);
```

Later on in code. He just uses

```
void sigint_handler (int signo)----> normal function returning void
{

}
```

can typedef be applied on functions

I want to know how it works

Answer (score 0):

> can typedef be applied on functions

Yes.....

> I want to know how it works

As the example you have read - the syntax is rather obscure (after 25 years of C I still have to think about it), but it is quite straight forward. Passing and storing pointers to functions is greatly simplified if you use typedefs.

I suggest either take a detour and learn about pointers to functions and typedefs of them, or take it as read for now and return to pointers to function later, as you cannot be a C programmer and avoid them.

Comment: Hi mattnz. Thank you for your suggestions. I am aware of pointers and function pointers and typedef. I did not apply typedef on functions.Later on when I applied typedef on functions its working,with function ptrs its working. If you are aware of those Signal API's please interpret me and make me clear

Answer (score 0):

A signal is just like a interrupt, when it is generated by user level, a call is made to the kernel of the OS and it will action accordingly. To create a signal, here I just show you an example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/types.h>   
void sig_handler1(int num)
{
   printf("You are here becoz of signal:%d\n",num);  
   signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_DFL);
}
void sig_handler(int num)
{
   printf("\nHi! You are here becz of signal:%d\n",num);
} 
int main()  
{ 
    signal(SIGINT,sig_handler1);
    signal(SIGQUIT,sig_handler);
    while(1)
   {
       printf("Hello\n");
       sleep(2);
   }

 }
```

after running this code if you will press Ctrl+C then a message will show - "You are here becoz of signal:2" instead of quiting a process as we have changed a signal according to our action. As, Ctrl+C is a maskable signal.

To know more anbout signals and types of signals with examples please follow the link :

http://www.firmcodes.com/signals-in-linux/